# Magento 2.0 cron job is working or not

Tags: magento-2.0

Now I am upset on the Cron job of Magento 2.0.

I have just installed Magento 2.0.4 and set the cron job using xampp.

I know if the cron job is working, I can see the schedule at 'cron_scehedule'.

But I cannot any internal cron job.

At the same time I tested with same ways using magento 1.0.

It works well.

Please let me know how can I test Magento 2.0 cron job is working or not.

Answer (score 4):

You have to run below command for schedule and run cron.

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Comment: how to use $_FILES while saving imported file[system config] ? as global variable we can't use @jaimin

Comment: Use below code : 
$this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$uploader = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader', ['fileId' => 'field_id']);
$csvFile = $uploader->validateFile()['tmp_name'];

Comment: Whats is field_id ? I have to pass $_FILES['groups']['tmp_name'] ? As I am using this system configuration

Comment: feild_id is name of element.